# Software to open ~.PTS file

Tags: windows, file-converter

Good day!

I have a file in ~.PTS format. It is a surveying output that should contain the following info:

1. Point Name, ex. STA-1
2. Eastings, similar to the x-coordinates
3. Northings, similar to the y-coordinates
4. Elevation, similar to the z-coordinate

The file was given by a surveyor after the survey activity and was generated from a software from HORIZON Total Stations. I tried to search for the software but I do not know its name.

Are there available software to convert these types to ~.TXT format? Thank you.

Comment: Is the file a text file? Does it contain the data in text format already?

Comment: I am not sure, however, the output I want should be in .txt format. When I try to open it, most numeric characters are in "random" symbols and letters.